# Add ability to remove individual tags when looking over unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, unanswered-questions

When looking at the set of unanswered questions I can click through the 'Unanswered Tags' to filter my results.  I can add multiple tag filters this way to show more results.

There should be a way to remove a single tag from my filter group.  Right now you either

1. Click 'Unanswered' again to clear all tags -or-
2. Click a single tag from the filter group as the new starting point

Starting with 3 tags you cannot remove just one to change your filters.  This is more of a discussion than a request at this time.

Comment: How about deleting it in the search field?

Comment: Or even the URL for that matter?  Looks like I was too focused on the clickable controls in that immediate tag cloud and not on other controls elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can delete [tags] from the search field to remove then from the filter